# check Box Item Table Widget Item

Tags: python, events, checkbox, pyqt5

i need just i check the checkbox it run the fun check_color_green directly without refresh ??help

#chkBoxItem = QTableWidgetItem()

#chkBoxItem.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

#chkBoxItem.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

#self.tableWidget_4.setItem(row_number, column_number, chkBoxItem)

#self.check_color_green(row_number)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please try to clarify and possibly provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: i need to enlarge the size  check box square which it inside table widget

Comment: Sorry but it's still not clear what you're asking. I know English is not your natural language, but you have to find a way to better explain what you need or find someone that could help you translate for you, otherwise nobody will actually be able to help you here.

Comment: i have table widget contains inside it check box square i need to enlarge square size